# amCharts: dynamic length of div container

Tags: amcharts

I found this:
https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/dynamic-chart-container-size-based-on-number-of-data-points/

```
AmCharts.addInitHandler( function ( chart ) {
  // set base values
  var categoryWidth = 25;

  // calculate bottom margin based on number of data points
  var chartHeight = categoryWidth * chart.dataProvider.length;

  // set the value
  chart.div.style.height = chartHeight + 'px';

}, ['serial'] );
```

In my case, I load the data via

```
"dataLoader": {
                "url": "/pages/trainingsProProjectChartData",
                "format": "json"
            },
```

How can I calculate

> chartHeight

in that case? How can I access the number of data from dataLoader?

UPDATE:

with

> console.log(chart.dataProvider.length);

I get 'chart.dataProvider is undefined'

> console.log(chart);

I can see the object 'dataProvider'!! and it contains all my data. But I can't access it?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you're using fires before the dataLoader runs, which is why the dataProvider is empty.

An easy way to work around this is to just put the code in the dataLoader's [`complete`](https://github.com/amcharts/dataloader/#using-callback-functions) callback. This will ensure it runs after the data has been loaded:

```
  "dataLoader": {
    "url": "/path/to/your/endpoint",
    "complete": function(chart) {
      // set base values
      var categoryWidth = 25;

      // calculate bottom margin based on number of data points
      var chartHeight = categoryWidth * chart.dataProvider.length;

      // set the value
      chart.div.style.height = chartHeight + 'px';
    }
  },
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/38ae46ed0a191b9231954f6e69817980?editors=0010)